# Trouble implementing a premade login system[C#]

Tags: c#, security

So i've purchased a system that upon purchase a user gets a generated key that they can use to validate their product. The company gave me a .dll to add to my references so that i may instantiate an object of their namespace and call it upon product launch so that the interface to validate the key would pop up. We are having a huge problem with getting this setup for me. I have the UGSec.dll in my references and when i put the code into InitializeComponent i get an error. It says the exception namespace can not be found.

I've included the error, and the code required for UGSec to startup below. Please help me solve this.

```
        try
        {
            UGSec.License UG = new UGSec.License();
            UG.ProgramKey = "AMWB8GIQFE-NLOOH48FLKZA";
            UG.ProgramVersion = "1.0.0";
            UG.Required();
        }
        catch (Exception Errorcode)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

and here is the error message

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'Exception' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Now im getting this error                                                                                                                                                                           An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in "program name"

Additional information: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Exception` to `System.Exception`, or put the line `using System;` at the top of the file.

Comment: This worked... but now i get this error                                                   An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in "program name"

Additional information: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.